# Query is too Complex exception in access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want to update 200 columns in a table in a single query using vb.net with ms-access. is there any other way to update the table or to split the table into two parts and then run the query?

```
//Function in my Module
Public Function selectdata(ByVal str as String) As DataTable
//str for passing the string which returns datatable in my function
cmd = new OleDbCommand(str,con)
adp = new OleDbAdapter(cmd)
cmdb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adp)
adp.fill(odt)
Return odt
End Function
```

The Datatable returns the table with 200 columns

```
//Onclick button Event
Dim dt As New DataTable
query = "SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE tableID = " & tb.Text
dt = selectdata(query)
{
    //My field values to be updated
}

adp.Update(dt)
```

After this it catches the exception of **"Query is too Complex"**

What should I do to split the table and update it into two parts  as 127 is the limit of Ms access for updating fields in a single Update query and I want to run the update query without splitting a single table into multiple tables.

Comment: 2 questions: why does one table have (more) 200 columns (Ever heard of normalization)? And why do you want to update em all at once? But since you've reached your max. Then yes, your obliged to split the query up in 2 (or more) parts.

Comment: i know what is normalization... but there are 200 columns in a single table as I am making an application for incometax e-filing process.. and that is what i am asking how to split the query as i am not using any update query... i am just using the update function of the dataadapter class.

Comment: you could manually generate you update query. As the datatable will contains the name of each column (of your table) as header in column datatable... It actually isn't that hard. perform the update in sections of 100 (or whatever quatity you desire). Be wary though that you use transactions, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Why do you have a mixture of VB and C# in your code sample?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the adapter is auto generating an update query for you.

This query will look like this:

```
UPDATE Column1 SET VALUE = 'foo' 
WHERE Column2 = 'bar' AND Column3 = 'bar' AND ...(every col)... Column200 = 'bar'
```

You just need to specify the Update query yourself using the primary key of the table in the WHERE clause